# what is this hybrid sleep mode? My computer simply cannot sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hybrid-sleep

So recently I noticed that my PC just does not want to go to sleep when I click start - sleep mode. The only thing that happens is that monitor becomes blank but all fans are still running at the same speed and the case LED lights don't switch off!
Fortunately I found out I can fix this weird issue if I disable the hybrid mode sleep in power options.
So my question is how did this happen? Probably via some windows update patch? And what should this be for? If this is a global change, then probably 99% of normal users will just stop using sleep because it simply doesn't work, so what's the reason for this weirdness?
I have fairly new PC with Ryzen 5600X and Windows 10

Comment: Check "ACPI power states" in BIOS. It usually can be either S1 or S3 or S1&S2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the BIOS of your machine. Check power related settings and ensure S3-S5 sleep aren't disabled. This setting may go by different name or be located in various places depending on your motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: my work laptop is sometimes doing it too - I make it go sleep but the fan is still on.

Comment: You can attempt to turn off hybrid sleep to see if this resolves the issue. Your work laptop most likely has policies applied to it by your system admin which might prevent you from making some necessary changes.

Comment: AMD Cool&Quiet was disabled. I think I did it because someone warned me that this can cause instability on this Ryzen CPU. So I enabled it again and enabled back hybrid sleep mode and it works as I want - everything silent and dark.